# Can I reduce the privileges level on mono's certificate machine store?

Tags: certificates, mono

I am running NUnit tests on Ubuntu via mono. They require the certmgr tool to install certificates and keys that the tests utilize. The user cert/key I can install fine, but the tests fall over if the CA certificate is not installed in the MACHINE rather than LOCAL USER Trust store.

However, the Machine store requires sudo to install certificates. The user running the tests, I don't want to give sudo privileges to.

Can I reduce the privileges required to install certificates to the machine store?

Comment: I assume you know you can give a user sudo limited to a specific program with specific argument(s), or if that's not strict enough, a script you write which carefully does only the exact thing(s) you want to permit this user to do.

Comment: good tip. I didn't know that. I will be able to proceed with that, thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The machine store keys and certificates are stored in the root user's home directory:

```
/root/.config/.mono/
```

However, when I `chmod`'d the subdirectories there to provide access to the user in question, it didn't work, I still got permission denied.

Instead, I'm taking dave_thompson_085's tip. I gave the user `sudo` access to mono's `certmgr` utility and now it's working well.